# ThreadPool behavior and TCPListener

Tags: c#, .net, threadpool, tcplistener

I am starting `TCPListener` like this and when the job done I close the `Socket`.
I would like to know if the `Thread` which I start like this

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ConnectClientsThredProc, args);
```

is going to destroy itself so I don't need any external control over it.

**Would anyone so pleased to explain have I worry about it or don't.**
Thank you!

```
   class TCPListenerManager
    {
        TcpListener tcpListener;
        HostListenerItem hostListener;
        private bool _isServerWorking = false;

     public TCPListenerManager(HostListenerItem hostListenerItem)
     {
         hostListener = hostListenerItem;

         tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(hostListenerItem.IP4), hostListenerItem.Port);

         var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
                {
                    await StartAsync(hostListenerItem.ClientsMax);
                });
            }

    public async Task StartAsync(int clientsMax)
    {
                    tcpListener.Start();
                    _isServerWorking = true;
                    for (int i = 0; i < clientsMax; i++)
                    {
                        if (_isServerWorking)
                        {
                            ServerConnectedEventArgs args = new ServerConnectedEventArgs();
                            args.TcpClient = await tcpListener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
                            args.HostListener = hostListener;

                            OnServerConnected(args);
                            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ConnectClientsThredProc, args);
                        }
   }
}


private void ConnectClientsThredProc(object obj)
{     
           var args = (ServerConnectedEventArgs)obj;

           if (args.TcpClient.Connected)
           {
              // Do some job and disconnect
              args.TcpClient.Client.Close();
              args.TcpClient.Client = null; 
           }
  }
}
```

Comment: the thread will run till the method it runs exits

Comment: @pm100 Do you mean after `args.TcpClient.Client = null; ` the `Thread` is still exists? So I need some event to fire  and via external code destroy this `Thread`?

Comment: however u should not run the tcp connection thread like that. The queueuserworkitem is intended for queued up background tasks. That not what you want, you need the connection to be handled now. Explicitly start a thread

Comment: no, once that method ends the thread is gone

Comment: @pm100 As I got I don't have bother about accumulating Threads but still have to redesign code. Please suggest your corrections.

Comment: `StartNew` does not work with async, you really should be using `Task.Run(` instead. (not related to your problem, but a best practices issue)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Thank you, please suggest your explanation like an answer.

Comment: I just said, it does ***not*** fix your problem, I was just warning you that [StartNew is dangerous](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `ConnectClientsThredProc` exits, thread is not "gone" but returned back to the pool (that's why thread pool exists in the first place). Anyway, you should not care about that indeed, unless you have long-running task performed in `ConnectClientsThredProc`. If it is long running - better not use thread pool thread, but start a new one (via `Task.Factory.StartNew` + `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` for example).

Also, you use `Task.Factory`, async\await, `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`, all that in a short piece of code, mixed together. Maybe you need to understand a bit better what are those tools and what are similarities and differences between them (especially async\await). For example, what is the reason for this:

```
var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
{
      await StartAsync(hostListenerItem.ClientsMax);
 });
```

You start a task\thread, inside which you start yet another task and then wait for it to exit - makes little sense.

Instead of `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` you might use `Task.Run` with the same effect.